# steam passport implementation, convert from express to nestjs

Tags: javascript, express, nestjs, passport.js

I've started to convert express project to nestjs. How should it work in Nestjs. Here is working code from Express.
(Code below just redirects to steam sign-in page)

```
/* eslint-disable space-before-function-paren */
// Require all the installs
var express = require('express');
var passport = require('passport');
var session = require('express-session');
var passportSteam = require('passport-steam');
var SteamStrategy = passportSteam.Strategy;
var app = express();
// Let's set a port
var port = 4000;
// Spin up the server
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log('Listening, port ' + port);
});

// Set up the SteamStrategy
// Required to get data from user for sessions
passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
  done(null, user);
});

passport.deserializeUser((user, done) => {
  done(null, user);
});

// Initiate Strategy
passport.use(
  new SteamStrategy(
    {
      returnURL: 'http://localhost:' + port + '/api/auth/steam/return',
      realm: 'http://localhost:' + port + '/',
      apiKey: 'My API key',
    },
    function (identifier, profile, done) {
      process.nextTick(function () {
        profile.identifier = identifier;
        return done(null, profile);
      });
    }
  )
);

app.use(
  session({
    secret: 'Whatever_You_Want',
    saveUninitialized: true,
    resave: false,
    cookie: {
      maxAge: 3600000,
    },
  })
);
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

// Routes
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send(req.user);
});
app.get(
  '/api/auth/steam',
  passport.authenticate('steam', { failureRedirect: '/' }),
  function (req, res) {
    res.redirect('/');
  }
);

app.get(
  '/api/auth/steam/return',
  passport.authenticate('steam', { failureRedirect: '/' }),
  function (req, res) {
    res.redirect('/');
  }
);
```

The question is how to implement same in the nestjs???
Or if I want to implement middlewares for passport lib (serializeUser, deserializeUser), how should it happen, in nest official docs I found this examples of custom middlewares

```
export function logger(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
  console.log(`Request...`);
  next();
};
```

But how I should use passport middlware

Comment: You may find your answer [here](https://docs.nestjs.com/security/authentication)

Answer (score 1):

In case you still need an answer here is how this should be done according to the Nestjs documentation:

*I will assume that you know how to setup a nest application and address the steam authentication*

1. Create a controller that handles `/steam/auth` path:

```
import { Controller, Get, Req, Res, UseGuards } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AuthGuard } from '@nestjs/passport';
import { Request, Response } from 'express';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';

@Controller('auth')
export class AuthController {
 constructor(private readonly authService: AuthService) {}

 @Get('steam')
 @UseGuards(AuthGuard('steam'))
 steamLogin() {}
}
```

2. Configure the steam strategy in a separate `steam.strategy` file:

```
import { Strategy } from 'passport-steam';
import { PassportStrategy } from '@nestjs/passport';
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';


@Injectable()
export class SteamStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy) { 
    super({
      returnURL: 'http://localhost:3001/auth/return',
      realm: 'http://localhost:3001/',
      apiKey: 'Your API key',
    });
  }
  validate(identifier, profile, done) {
     // add your code that is to be executed after the login succeeds here
     
  }
```

3. Don't forget to import the strategy inside of your `auth.module`:

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { SteamStrategy } from './steam.strategy';
@Module({
  providers: [SteamStrategy],
})
export class AuthModule {}
```

That's all. After that you can continue the same way you would using express!